# My sitemap.xml have a different domain and this is an error

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I have created a site with a development domain name. Now this site is online (camperlife.it), but sitemap.xml created by [XML sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module still contains the development domain name.

I have rebuilt sitemap many times, but without success.

Where is my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a setting wrong.

Browse to the XML Sitemap settings page (admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings).

Expand the **Advanced Settings** section.

Check/set the **Default Base URL**.  Typically, I set this to make sure the default base URL gets used, as rebuilding from drush won't set it properly if you don't `$uri` set in your site alias.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but in "Default base URL" I have my domain site in form of http://www.mydomain.ext. The only thing that I can think is that for some strange reason, xmlsitemap module get the sitename from machine and not from this setting.